# Stop playing after queue ends in cmus

Tags: cmus

I'd like to be able to queue songs and play the queue and I would also like for the playback to end when the queue ends. Currently another song is played when the queue ends (I haven't quite been able to figure out how that song is chosen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `stop_after_queue` tells cmus to stop playback after the play queue is exhausted:

```
:set stop_after_queue=true
```

Comment: Thank you, my distro still shipped an outdated version that does not have this option.